# How do I build a video chat application using python

Tags: python, videochat, video-conferencing

Just finished my studies on python 3, build some app and I want to on to my main project. Please how can I build a video chat application using python

Answer (score 1):

That is quite an ambition challenge! I would start by writing a GUI interface so that users can start/end/pause the video call and mute their camera or microphone. Tkinter, wxPython, and PyQt are a few decent ones. After that, I would do some research on networking and figure out how to send the video to and from each recipient. I would look into RTP (Real-Time Transport Protocol) for that. You could even establish a UDP connection between the two. The number of approaches are endless! I encourage you to do some more in-depth research before you begin.

**Note that this process would be different if you were to make a video chat website.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want it to be both a video chat website and app for both Phone and PC